# Pickup address doesn't show extra options

Tags: commerce, 9

I'm using the [Commerce Pickup](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pickup) module. I've added 2 pickup profiles (just like [Drupal Commerce Pickup module 8.x / 9.x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=wiJkbQu_ffc) shows), but when I try to add it to my shipping method as *Customer > Pickup address*, it doesn't show the extra options.

> [image: screenshot]

When I save, it gives this error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I've seen in [Drupal Commerce Pickup module 8.x / 9.x](https://youtu.be/wiJkbQu_ffc?t=1150) that it should give extra options.

> [image: Screenshot options in tutorial for shipping method]

I'm guessing this is the reason for the unexpected error.

When I enable the pickup hours selectbox, it does give options, but if I select the pickup address and I add the pickup hours, it doesn't give any option (not for address nor for the pickup hours). The pickup address is a required value; only entering the pickup hours is not possible.

Comment: Unexpected errors usually are logged. What are the error details?

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
It says: Notice: Trying to get property 'entity' of non-object in commerce_pickup_form_alter() (line 109 of /www/modules/contrib/commerce_pickup/commerce_pickup.module) 
Ill go and check that out, if I find anything, Ill post it here. (Please don't let that stop anyone else from joining my search :) .)

Comment: ^error is nothing, it just says on the pickup point that it cannot load a user image..
There are 2 other errors I get.
I've posted an issue in the drupal module issuetracker: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pickup/issues/3308313